# Domain of a function -issue

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have the following function
$y=\sqrt{(1- \ln(x^2 +7x+10))}$

The book says the domain is $x \in [-7,-5) \cup (-2,0]$.

What I've done is:

Condition 1

the argument of the logarithm higher than zero: $x^2 +7x+10>0$,

from which I get : $x \in (- \infty,-5)\cup(-2, \infty)$

Condition 2

What is under the square root, must be non-negative:

$\ln(x^2+7x+10)\le 1$

And this should imply
$x^2 +7x+10 \le e$

but I think that there is something wrong right here. Indeed, when intersect condition 1 and 2, I do not get the right answer.Why?

Comment: For example, there is no way $-6$ is in the domain of that function.

Comment: I agree with you. But, why when intersect condition 1 and 2, I do not get the right answer?

Comment: @JohnM. seems that the author of the book is wrong

Comment: Right.  Most likely an honest typo.

Comment: Thanks so much, It must be just like you said, a typo. Sorry for the waste of time

Comment: Not a waste of time.

Comment: [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oyxf1dmynh) of $y$. The author it definitely off